# TOR browser and local proxy

Tags: proxy

Why the TOP browser does not connect to the network, I have a local proxy server in the building, I enter the address and port in the TOP setting, but the connection does not occur.

Comment: Your information are very vague and currently it is unclear what your question is about. Please add more details (operating system, log messages etc.)? This helps to answer the question.

Comment: Any logs? Please be more detailed about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

En: Tor browser can be filtered out by your proxy. Use pluggable transports
RU: ТОР браузер может быть отфильтрован Вашим прокси. Используйте подключаемые транспорты